# RMarkdown, knitr::kable shows "\begin{table}" after knitting to pdf document

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

One of cells in my RMarkdown document

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
head(data,3) %>% knitr::kable(caption = "Pierwsze 3 wiersze ze zbioru danych Lista_1.csv", digits = 2, booktabs = T)
````

gives weird result after knitting to pdf:
[image]

Of course there shouldn't be "\begin{table}" ,"\caption{}" and "\end{table}" parts. I use `knitr::kable` often and it never worked this way. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Edit: I have also noticed that all section headers (like "##Section2") below the table are centered. They shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found this question: [How do I prevent kable from leaving raw latex in the final document if I include a caption in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850407/how-do-i-prevent-kable-from-leaving-raw-latex-in-the-final-document-if-i-include?rq=1)
and used tip from comment (`format = pandoc`). It worked for me.